# How to remove a column from excel sheet in epplus

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm using csharp to insert data into excel sheet into 7 columns. The interface of this program will allow users to select 7 checkboxes. If they select all 7, all the 7 columns in spreadhseet will have data, if they select one checkbox then only one column will have data. I have got a for loop which will check if data is there, if no data exists, I want to remove that column in epplus. Here's a previous discussion on this topic 
[How can I delete a Column of XLSX file with EPPlus in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170717/how-can-i-delete-a-column-of-xlsx-file-with-epplus-in-web-app) 
It's quiet old so I just wanna check if there's a way to do this.
Or, is there a way to cast epplus excel sheet to microsoft interop excel sheet and perform some operations.

Currently, I've code like this:

```
for(int j=1; j <= 9; j++) //looping through columns
{
int flag = 0;
for(int i = 3; i <= 10; i++) // looping through rows
{
    if(worksheet.cells[i, j].Text != "")
    {
        flag ++;
    }
}
if (flag == 0)
{
     worksheet.column[j].hidden = true; // hiding the columns- want to  remove it
}
}
```

Can we do something like:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlApp = worksheet; (where worksheet is epplus worksheet)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you using EPPlus 4?  The ability to do column inserts and deletion was added with the new Cell store model they implemented.  So you can now do something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void DeleteColumn_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359165/how-to-remove-a-column-from-excel-sheet-in-epplus

    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1"));
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2"));
    datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3"));

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row["Col1"] = "Col1 Row" + i;
        row["Col2"] = "Col2 Row" + i;
        row["Col3"] = "Col3 Row" + i;
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    using (var pack = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {

        var ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Content");
        ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        ws.DeleteColumn(2);

        pack.SaveAs(existingFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using Epplus 3.1.3.0. I'll try to find a way to update it to version 4 and then try your solution. Cheers.

Comment: Works fine for epplus4.

Comment: @sanmis Cool, glad it works for you.  They added a bunch of good stuff to version 4.  Just remember the mark the question as answered to close it out.

Comment: What if I just want to remove certain columns without adding stuff to it first?

Comment: @Si8 Not sure I follow.  The above example adds data just so there is this actually something to delete.  The `DeleteColumn` function should work just fine by itself.  If I am misunderstanding maybe post a new question with your code.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So am I just removing the following line: `ws.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true)` if I want to just delete the column?

Comment: Any idea why my cell is shifting up rather than the entire row? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41170869/how-to-delete-entire-row-if-a-match-is-made-in-a-cell-in-that-row. I would like the entire row to be deleted and the rest of the rows to shift up.