# EPPlus: Deleting column not working

Tags: epplus

I tried using EPPlus to delete a column in my worksheet using the solution in: [How to remove a column from excel sheet in epplus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359165/how-to-remove-a-column-from-excel-sheet-in-epplus)

However, when I run this unit test, the data in column 2 simply gets cleared out. How do I remove a column altogether?

Comment: Maybe you should consider provide us a snippet of what you've tried.

Comment: I used the unit test solution on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359165/how-to-remove-a-column-from-excel-sheet-in-epplus

Specifically ws.DeleteColumn(2) simply clears out all the data in column 2, but does not delete the column itself.

Answer (score 4):

Thats interesting.  Seems the added it in 4.0.0 and then broke it with version 4.0.4:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15310

If you are desperate you can download the source code and go bacck to the original version of the `DeleteColumn` function (in ExcelWorksheet.cs) and recompile:

```
public void DeleteColumn(int columnFrom, int columns)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        ExcelColumn col = _values.GetValue(0, columnFrom) as ExcelColumn;
        if (col == null)
        {
            var r = 0; 
            var c = columnFrom;
            if(_values.PrevCell(ref r,ref c))
            {
                col = _values.GetValue(0, c) as ExcelColumn;
                if(col._columnMax >= columnFrom)
                {
                    col.ColumnMax=columnFrom-1;
                }
            }
        }

        _values.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _types.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _formulas.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _styles.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _flags.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _commentsStore.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);
        _hyperLinks.Delete(1, columnFrom, ExcelPackage.MaxRows, columns);

        AdjustFormulasColumn(columnFrom, columns);
        FixMergedCellsColumn(columnFrom, columns, true);

        var csec = new CellsStoreEnumerator<object>(_values, 0, columnFrom, 0, ExcelPackage.MaxColumns);

        foreach (var column in csec)    
        {
            if (column is ExcelColumn)
            {
                var c = (ExcelColumn)column;
                if (c._columnMin >= columnFrom)
                {
                    c._columnMin -= columns;
                    c._columnMax -= columns;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var tbl in Tables)
        {
            if (columnFrom > tbl.Address.Start.Column && columnFrom <= tbl.Address.End.Column)
            {
                var node = tbl.Columns[0].TopNode.ParentNode;
                var ix = columnFrom - tbl.Address.Start.Column + 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++)
                {
                    if (node.ChildNodes.Count > ix)
                    {
                        node.RemoveChild(node.ChildNodes[ix]);
                    }

                } 
                tbl._cols = new ExcelTableColumnCollection(tbl);
            }

            tbl.Address = tbl.Address.DeleteColumn(columnFrom, columns);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I reverted to 4.0.3 and it's working now. I will wait until the next release to upgrade.

Comment: @RussellBoada  No problem.  Just remember to make the question as answered so it doesnt hang out there.